# why I am getting this error "RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 1: 1,"?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting "RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 1: 1
" when I am doing crossAxisCount: 2 or more? plz anyone help me in solving this out.....

```
    GridView.builder(gridDelegate:  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2,
     mainAxisSpacing: 16,
     crossAxisSpacing: 16,
   ),
```

Comment: I think it is coming from `children`, can you check the list length and paste full code of `GridView`?

Comment: This is arrayoutofboundexception for dart.

Comment: Your code very small . We cant reproduce and get error.!